# Create a dynamic function without eval() or Function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, content-security-policy

I have a function body in a string. Say,

> str is "return a+b"

for a function that takes two arguments **a** and **b**.
How to create a *anonymous (or named)* function from this string?
I am trying to make application **Content Security Policy** compliant and therefore using **eval** and **Function** constructor is not an option.
Apparently, this can be done using *prototypes* maybe. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like someone's homework...

Comment: Is this string coded in client-side or you get it from a database or...?

Comment: If you're trying to find a complicated hack to dance around something a security policy you are choosing to follow bans… then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Actually I have a piece of code that uses Function.apply. I'm trying to port the code to a implementation that does not require the use of eval() or Function constructor, which are deemed unsecure by CSP.

Comment: But I'm clueless as to how to proceed. I'm not asking for a full written solution, just an idea to proceed. Also, can it be done?

Comment: Step 1: Why are you dynamically creating source code on the fly at all? If you dynamically fetch "rules" from somewhere, write a rule evaluation engine that can parse `"a + b"` and give you the appropriate result. Don't write `"return a + b"` somewhere dynamically and expect to run it as Javascript code.

Comment: @deceze I get that my way is not the correct way to do things, but even if I were to do it my way, would that be even possible?

Comment: Content Security Policy prohibits the *dynamic evaluation of Javascript* for security reasons. What you're trying to do is *dynamic evaluation of Javascript*. That is prohibited for security reasons by the Content Security Policy. If there was a simple way to simply do it a little differently somehow which would still allow you to *dynamically evaluate Javascript*, the Content Security Policy would be pretty useless and broken.

Comment: Can I whitelist my code snippet instead of using 'unsafe-eval'?

Comment: What is your evaluated code supposed to do? Why do you need dynamically generated functions?

Comment: The problem with evaluating *any* code dynamically is that it introduces a vector for attackers to introduce their own code *as value*. That's a security problem. To eliminate that security problem, you can explicitly declare that you won't ever do any such thing. If you "whitelist" some of your code to allow it to evaluate dynamic code, guess what, you reintroduced that security problem, which makes the Content Security Policy pointless.

Comment: Still, CSP is not a comprehensive solution anyway. Even if I don't whitelist my code, there is still a lot of room for attackers. Although, it would be more secure than a page without CSP.

Comment: Still, thanks for your input @deceze